# Concatenate cell range if data exists in another cell in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that I dump into Excel from a PDF that I want to parse.

Part of that code causes Excel to run Text to Columns on the data with a space delimiter. Most rows will be fine, but sometimes there are spaces in names.

I am trying to add code that will look at each row to see if data is in a cell, and if so, concatenate other cells.

From a similar project, I have code that does this, but it instead deletes cells to make the rows all the same size. An example of that is:

```vb
Sub FixRows()

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To 20000 Step 1
        If Not IsEmpty(Range("Q" & i)) Then Range("B" & i & ":I" & i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Next i

End Sub
```

I also have code in a project that creates a formula for three cells, concatenating the data and then deleting the original cells:

```vb
Columns("D:D").Insert
Dim LastRow As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
        .Formula = "=A1&"" ""&B1&"" ""&C1"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
Columns("A:C").Delete
```

I am trying to combine these ideas. I last tried this:

```vb
Sub TestConcat()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 20000 Step 1
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("J" & i)) Then Range("A" & i).Formula = "A" & i & " " & "B" & i.Value = .Value
    Range("B" & i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next i
        
End Sub
```

I get a compiler error on the second "i".

> "Invalid Qualifier"

---

Tim Williams' comment provided the syntax.
Be sure to alter the Delete portion of the code. The way I wrote it deletes Column "B" throughout the spreadsheet.

```vb
Sub TestConcat()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 20000 Step 1
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("J" & i)) Then Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & Range("B" & i).Value
    If Not IsEmpty(Range("J" & i)) Then Range("B" & i).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Next i
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & " " & Range("B" & i).Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the values directly. For example

```
Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value & " " & Range("B" & i).Value
```